# Store object value in type table

Tags: oracle, plsql

Following id the Code to store object value in array of type table.

Object Creation :

```
Create or replace type t_loc as Object
    (
      name varchar2(255 byte),
      idt char(2)
    );
```

PLSQL Block

```
set serveroutput on;
  declare 
     TYPE test1 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100) INDEX BY t_loc;
     test2 test1;
  begin
    test2('abad')  := t_loc('ahmedabad','CT');
    test2('bang')  := t_loc('bangalure','S');
    test2('surat')  :=t_loc('Surat','C');

    dbms_output.put_line(test2('surat'));

  end;
```

I am not able to compile upper code.
Is it not possible in oracle ? or is there anything wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want a table of strings, indexed by your custom type? Or do you want a table of your custom type, indexed by strings? Anyway, the declaration of `test1` does not match how you use it below.

Try the following code:

```
declare 
    TYPE test1 IS TABLE OF t_loc INDEX BY VARCHAR2(100);
    test2 test1;
begin
    test2('abad')  := t_loc('ahmedabad','CT');
    test2('bang')  := t_loc('bangalure','S');
    test2('surat') := t_loc('Surat','C');

    dbms_output.put_line(test2('surat').name);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got the solution following is the code.

```
set serveroutput on;
      declare 
         TYPE test1 IS TABLE OF t_loc INDEX BY varchar2(100);
         test2 test1;
      begin
        test2('abad')  := t_loc('ahmedabad','CT');
        test2('bang')  := t_loc('bangalure','S');
        test2('surat')  :=t_loc('Surat','C');

        dbms_output.put_line(test2('surat').name);

      end;
```